# "Server Selection Timeout Error" MongoDB Go Driver with Docker

Tags: mongodb, docker, go

I'm working on a very basic (I thought) starter program in Go using MongoDB and Docker. Trying to get a handle on these before we start using them at work.
I've got my MongoDB running in a docker container, just using my local host, using the official Docker image. This is running fine, I can connect to it through MongoDB Compass and modify the DB.

My next task was to build a separate Docker container that is able to read and write to the DB. I'm using MongoDB-Go-Driver (https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo) for this as mgo is no longer kept up.

This is my code, I'm just following the numerous tutorials online to make a simple connection and then ping the DB to ensure connectivity.

```
client, err := mongo.Connect("mongodb://localhost:27017")

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("error ", err)
}

// Check the connection
err = client.Ping(context.TODO(), nil)

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("error2 ", err)
}

fmt.Println("Connected to MongoDB!")
```

It always fails on doing any operation on the DB (Find, FindOne, Ping, etc.) with `error2 server selection timeout`

This is my docker-compose file I'm running.

```
version: "3"

services:
  datastore:
    image: mongo
    ports: 
      - "27017:27017"
    networks: 
      - maccaptionNet
    volumes: 
      - .:/go/src/maccaption_microservice/dbdata
  jobservice:
    image: jobservicemaccaption:1.0
    networks:
      - maccaptionNet
    depends_on:
      - "datastore"


networks: 
  maccaptionNet:
    driver: bridge
```

I'm brand new to MongoDB and after hours of research haven't made any progress on this.
I've read through https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference-mechanics/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/

Can anyone point me in the right direction for this? I haven't been able to find a lot on this specific issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your docker-compose? If you are trying to run the service from docker as well you will need to connect to the mongo service name as in docker-compose and not to `localhost`

Comment: @oren added the docker-compose above. Thanks!

Comment: Is `jobservice` your go service?

Comment: Yes - using the image I built from the go code above that.

Comment: So you need to connect with the service name for that mongodb container `datastore`, you can try my answer

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you running the service and `mongodb` in docker you can't use  `localhost` since the service is in a different container than `mongodb`, and from docker point of view it's under a different ip address.

You can connect with the service name you specify in docker-compose `datastore`

```
mongo.Connect("mongodb://datastore:27017")
```

**Edit:**

from: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

> By default Compose sets up a single network for your app. Each
>   container for a service joins the default network and is both
>   reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by
>   them at a hostname identical to the container name

Meaning that if you run multiple containers via compose, you can access one container from the other by the container name,

Basically when `docker-compose` starts, it sets up the network, and each container in the compose joins the network under its container name. For a container's point if view, `localhost` is just the container itself, while he can search for other container's name and get back the container’s IP address.

Assuming that the docker is running on your localhost, you can set the name in `etc/hosts` file like this:

```
127.0.0.1 datastore
```

(if not just replace `127.0.0.1` with the docker ip)

And in the app you will connect with `mongodb://datastore:27017`

So you will be able to run the service both in the docker and from outside, if you'll decide to run only the `db` in docker

```
docker-compose start datastore
```

Comment: I modified my `client, err := mongo.Connect("mongodb://localhost:27017")` statement to be `client, err := mongo.Connect("mongodb://jobservice:27017")` but I'm still getting the same timeout error.

Comment: @henleyhoudini  Not `jobservice`. use `datastore`, as this is the mongodb container service name

Comment: Just so I know I'm understanding this correctly - I need to use the name of the Docker container I'm using instead of the actual local host because the DB is stored in the localhost for the Docker Container and not technically my localhost?

Comment: @henleyhoudini Yep, you are basically correct. I edited my answer a bit to give some more details. Hope it make sense

Comment: @oren in my case I have mongodb in docker but mongo.Connect is running outside a docker in my local computer. how can I solve this error

Answer (score 2):

If you are connecting to one docker from another (like it is written in your `docker-compose` file, and using `bridge` network mode, you have to change your `localhost` to the hostname, like `datastore`

```
client, err := mongo.Connect("mongodb://datastore:27017")
```

When your `go` script uses `localhost`, it expects the database to located in the same docker

Answer (score 1):

I think my answer might be unrelated but still, I was getting the same error and it was because my IP address was not listed in the IP whitelist tab in MongoDB atlas, so make sure you have your IP address there before trying to connect.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but found another way to address this issue. You can just pass network parameter while running docker image and this way docker points to correct localhost.

`docker run --network="host" ....`

[Source for this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Answer (score 0):

Somehow i've fix this problem in a different way: by changing `ports` from `"27018:27017"` to `"27017:27017"`.
IDK why this helps. Maybe if Mongo sees not default port it thinks there are cluster of Mongo's nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem when I tired to connect to

```
mongodb v4.0.10
```

with

```
pymongo==4.0.2  not worked 
pymongo==3.12.3 worked
```

Check your packages
`mongodb v5.0.2` works with `pymongo==4.0.2`